# pvcreate on a ext3 partition, is it dangerous?

Tags: linux, partition, ext3, lvm

I know pvcreate a LVM physical volume usually on a LVM partition, but I do a pvcreate on a empty ext3 partition accidentally, is this dangerous, do I really need to repartition with LVM format on the target disk?

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine. I'm pretty sure the "format" you would select in fdisk is really nothing more than a label.

With that said, changing a partition type is an easy process. You only need to use fdisk's 't' command. The type for LVM is '8e'.

Comment: Some OSes care about partition types, but Linux doesn't (it only looks for signatures inside the partitions) except for extended partitions (i.e. containers for logical partitions).